# php to save to file without submit button

Tags: php, forms

I've posted this question before a bit less specific last time and with no exp on it. 
I have looked in to the matter and got a bit further but I need some help 
I have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#name").keyup(function() {
        $("#idOfPElementWhichYouWantToEdit").text($(this).val());
    });
</script>
<p id="idOfPElementWhichYouWantToEdit"></p>
<input name="name" id="name" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"/>

<?php
$file = "logger.txt";
$handle = fopen($file,'a+') or die("can't open file");
$logged = $_POST['name'];
    $handed = $logged . "\n";
fwrite($handle, $handed);

?>
```

It might have a couple lines extra but I'm messing with it. 
The main goal of it is to save to a text file while it is being typed in to. (NO need for a submit button) 
I would appreciate any help or suggestions to the code. 
Thanks

Comment: use `ajax` for this task...

Comment: `Depending on the browser, the Enter key may only cause a form submission if the form has exactly one text field, or only when there is a submit button present. The interface should not rely on a particular behavior for this key unless the issue is forced by observing the keypress event for presses of the Enter key.` Why you don't want that button?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add form tag

```
   <form id="file_form"><input></form>
```

and in JS this event need to be called

```
   $(#file_form).submit()
```

Comment: so then i need to use php and js :o

Comment: okay so once i add that it should work how i want it? @Grey2k

Answer (score 0):

Add form tag's and use that to call your onkeypress event.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="saveForm()">
```

Then just make you saveForm() over right the file.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @yogesh. use ajax for this task.
I have found some link which may similar to your problem and useful to you.

1 - http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/live-table-edit-with-jquery-and-ajax.html.
2 - http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/.

Just you have to change code to store data in  logger.txt instead of DB.

Comment: Thanks for this:) will definitely look into it

Comment: You should vote up any answers to this question that you found helpful, and accept the one answer that best helped you. These actions help reward those who contributed their time to help you, they help future users of the site with similar questions find the best answer, they encourage people to answer your future questions, and they help your reputation